# Xcode7: Can't Create IBOutlet To UIViewcontroller External View

Tags: swift, iboutlet, accessoryview

Starting Xcode7, I received error on creating `IBOutlet` to my keyboard accessory view:

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key keyboardAccessoryView.'

How to properly connect this accessory view?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Where and how is the outlet defined?

Comment: Your question leads me to check the class (.swift) file for `FeedbackViewController`. I turns out the `FeedbackViewController` swift file is not included in `target` > `Build Phases` > `Compile Sources`. Thanks anyway. It's working now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key